# Using properties immiedatly or use temporary variables while configuring?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I have a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* lblUsername;
```

Should I in `viewDidLoad` do this:

```
self.lblUsername = [[[UILabel alloc] init...] autorelease];
self.lblUsername.text = @"A label";
self.lblUsername....
```

Or should I do this:

```
UILabel* usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init...];
usernameLabel.text = @"A label";
usernameLabel....
self.lblUsername = usernameLabel;
[usernameLabel release];
```

I have seen both and I am unsure which I should use, any benefits of using one over another? (I know both are "correct" in syntax and both work, but which is preferred?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the second one every time. Besides the important fact that it makes little sense to stick half-constructed objects in your public interface (even if you don't *yet* have a codepath that could expose the bug), the second way is more efficient with zero cost. For every `self.thing.otherThing =`, you're sending a minimum of two messages, and more if you someday get KVO involved. There is absolutely no benefit to that indirection — it doesn't make your code read more clearly, it doesn't make it more concise, it doesn't make it safer, nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the second method.  The only real benefit is reducing stress on the autorelease pool, which is minimal if only initializing a few objects like this.  It's unlikely that you are modifying that property on another thread that could potentially cause unintended behavior if using the first method, but I suppose that is a risk.  To me it also seems to be the difference of building a component and then installing it versus installing an unfinished component then building it in place.